# stop the video in mfc with thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, video, mfc, tracking

I read a program with MFC visual studio 2013 that load a video from file and the we can track a object. I set a stop button. it work for loading video and stop the loading. but I can't stop the running video in tracking. it's my gui program:

```
bool Cgui2Dlg::getImageFilePath()
{
m_inputVideo.GetWindowTextW(file_path_);

if (file_path_.GetLength() > 0)
    return true;
else
{
    AfxMessageBox(L"Please, select one video file or image sequence    folder!");
    //return false;
}
}

Size Cgui2Dlg::getWindowSizeByID(int IDC) {
return getWindowSize(GetDlgItem(IDC)->m_hWnd);
}





void Cgui2Dlg::openfile()
{
    getImageFilePath();
CT2CA filePath2(file_path_);
string fp(filePath2);
VideoCapture capture(fp);
Mat frame;

if (!capture.isOpened())
    throw "Error when reading steam_avi";
 run_ = true;


///// show on the window frame
while (run_) {

    capture >> frame;
    if (frame.empty())
    {
        run_ = false;
        break;
    }

    auto input_size = getWindowSizeByID(IDC_Video_Original);


    view1_.create(input_size, CV_8UC3);

    rect1_ = ZoomWithSpect(frame, view1_, cofi_, Scalar::all(0));

    matToWinControl(view1_, &m_original_frame);
    ///

    SendMessage(WM_MSG, 0, 0);
    waitKey(400); // waits to display frame


    this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(interval_));
}
    if (run_) {
        run_ = false;
        OnBnClickedStop();
    }


}



void Cgui2Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1()

 {
//CFileDialog dlg(TRUE, _T("*.avi"), NULL,
//OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY, _T("video files (*.bmp; *.jpg; *.avi) |*.bmp;*.jpg;|All Files (*.*)|*.*||"), NULL);

//dlg.m_ofn.lpstrTitle = _T("Open Video");


//CString file_path_ = dlg.GetPathName(); // the selected filename                      // This is image pointer
setButtonsState(EcvButtonState::BUTTON1);
UpdateData(TRUE);
interval_ = 25;
std::thread t(&Cgui2Dlg::openfile, this);
t.detach();
}




void Cgui2Dlg::OnBnClickedButton3()
{

setButtonsState(EcvButtonState::BUTTON3);
UpdateData(TRUE);
interval_ = 200;
std::thread tt(&Cgui2Dlg::trackingfile, this);
tt.detach();
}
void Cgui2Dlg::trackingfile()
 {
getImageFilePath();

CT2CA filePath2(file_path_);
string fp(filePath2);
run_ = true;
//VideoCapture capture(fp);
//Mat frame;
//capture >> frame;


setButtonsState(EcvButtonState::BUTTON3);

//check radio botton for choosing one algorithm
int checkradio = GetCheckedRadioButton(IDC_RADIO1, IDC_RADIO2);

switch (checkradio)
{
case IDC_RADIO1:
{
    auto input_size = getWindowSizeByID(IDC_Video_Track);

    view2_.create(input_size, CV_8UC3);




    //rect1_ = ZoomWithSpect(frame, view1_, cofi_, Scalar::all(0));

    //matToWinControl(view2_, &m_Track_frame);

    //FCAMshift CAM(fp);//,run_);
        //CAM.track(fp); //, run_);

    FRunTracker CAM(fp);//,run_);
    CAM.track(fp); //, run_);
    //CAM.showresult();



    ///

    //waitKey(40); // waits to display frame
    //this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(interval_));
}
if (run_) {
    run_ = false;
    OnBnClickedStop();
}
break;


case IDC_RADIO2:
{

    auto input_size = getWindowSizeByID(IDC_Video_Track);

    view2_.create(input_size, CV_8UC3);

    FCAMshift CAM(fp);//,run_);
    CAM.track(fp); //, run_);


                   ///

                   //waitKey(40); // waits to display frame
    this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(interval_));
}
if (run_) {
    run_ = false;
    OnBnClickedStop();
}
break;

}
}


void Cgui2Dlg::setButtonsState(const EcvButtonState& state) {
switch (state)
{
case EcvButtonState::BUTTON1:

    m_stop_btn.EnableWindow(TRUE);
    m_Track_btn.EnableWindow(TRUE);
    m_load_btn.EnableWindow(TRUE);

    break;
case EcvButtonState::BUTTON3:

    m_stop_btn.EnableWindow(TRUE);
    m_Track_btn.EnableWindow(TRUE);
    m_load_btn.EnableWindow(TRUE);
    break;

case EcvButtonState::stop:
    m_stop_btn.EnableWindow(TRUE);
    m_Track_btn.EnableWindow(TRUE);
    m_load_btn.EnableWindow(TRUE);

    break;
}
//UpdateData(FALSE);
```

}

```
void Cgui2Dlg::OnBnClickedRadio1()
{
// TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
}


void Cgui2Dlg::OnBnClickedButton2()
{
run_ = false;
setButtonsState(EcvButtonState::stop);
}


void Cgui2Dlg::OnBnClickedRadio2()
{
// TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
}

void Cgui2Dlg::OnStnClickedVideoTrack()
{

 }

void Cgui2Dlg::OnStnClickedVideoOriginal()
{
// TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
}

LRESULT Cgui2Dlg::onUpdateUI(WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) {
matToWinControl(view1_, &m_original_frame);
//matToWinControl(view2_, &m_result_frame);

return 0;
}

void Cgui2Dlg::OnBnClickedStop()
{
run_ = false;
interval_ = 2000;
UpdateData(TRUE);

setButtonsState(EcvButtonState::stop);
}
```

and this  is my tracking code:

```
/************************************************************************
* File: RunTracker.cpp
************************************************************************/
   #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
  #include <sstream>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include "CompressiveTracker.h"
  #include "RunTracker.h"
  using namespace cv;
  using namespace std;

FRunTracker::FRunTracker(string x) //,bool y)
{
fp = x;
//run_=  y;
}



Mat src2, img2, ROI2, image2;
Rect box(0, 0, 0, 0);
Point Pi1(0, 0);
Point Pi2(0, 0);

const char* winName2 = "compressive tracking demo";
bool click = false;


void showimage22() {
img2 = src2.clone();
//checkBoundary();
if (box.width>0 && box.height>0) {
    ROI2 = src2(box);
    //imshow("cropped", ROI2);
}

rectangle(img2, box, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1, 8, 0);
imshow(winName2, img2);
}


void onMouse2(int event, int x, int y, int f, void*) {


switch (event) {

case  CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
    click = true;

    Pi1.x = x;
    Pi1.y = y;
    Pi2.x = x;
    Pi2.y = y;
    break;

case  CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
    Pi2.x = x;
    Pi2.y = y;
    click = false;
    //trackObject = -1;
    break;

case  CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
    if (click) {
        Pi2.x = x;
        Pi2.y = y;
    }
    break;

default:   break;


}


if (click) {
    if (Pi1.x>Pi2.x) {
        box.x = Pi2.x;
        box.width = Pi1.x - Pi2.x;
    }
    else {
        box.x = Pi1.x;
        box.width = Pi2.x - Pi1.x;
    }

    if (Pi1.y>Pi2.y) {
        box.y = Pi2.y;
        box.height = Pi1.y - Pi2.y;
    }
    else {
        box.y = Pi1.y;
        box.height = Pi2.y - Pi1.y;
    }

}


showimage22();


}

 void FRunTracker::track(string fp)
 {

VideoCapture input_video(fp);

input_video >> src2;
namedWindow(winName2, WINDOW_NORMAL);
setMouseCallback(winName2, onMouse2, NULL);
imshow(winName2, src2);
waitKey(0);

// CT framework
CompressiveTracker ct;

Mat grayimg2;


cvtColor(src2, grayimg2, CV_RGB2GRAY);
ct.init(grayimg2, box);

char strFrame[20];

//FILE* resultStream;
//resultStream = fopen("TrackingResults.txt", "w");
//fprintf(resultStream, "%i %i %i %i\n", (int)box.x, (int)box.y, (int)box.width, (int)box.height);

while (1) {

        input_video >> src2;

        if (src2.empty())
            break;

    cvtColor(src2, grayimg2, CV_RGB2GRAY);

    ct.processFrame(grayimg2, box);// Process frame

    rectangle(src2, box, Scalar(200, 0, 0), 2);// Draw rectangle

    //fprintf(resultStream, "%i %i %i %i\n", (int)box.x, (int)box.y, (int)box.width, (int)box.height);

    //sprintf(strFrame, "#%d ", i);

    //putText(src2, strFrame, cvPoint(0, 20), 2, 1, CV_RGB(25, 200, 25));

    imshow("Compressive Tracking", src2);// Display
    waitKey(1);
}
//fclose(resultStream);

 }


 FRunTracker::~FRunTracker()
 {
 }
```

Comment: Being new to C++ reduces your chances to 0 to use MFC proficiently. Not going to happen. Building a window hierarchy across threads is - while technically possible - so involved, that even seasoned developers will try anything to prevent it. Anyway, this question is unlikely to be helpful to future visitors. Voted to close.

Answer (score 0):

Your track function in FRunTracker class has a forever loop. Instead, put a boolean condition to check (like while(isRunning), etc) in the loop, and make the functions of your Cgui2Dlg class to change this condition. Don't forget to protect it with mutexes.

Comment: I'm new in C++ programming. can you explain more. if you can write some code I'll be so thankful. how can I change the condition in Cgui2Dlg?